# Entity Framework - Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Invalid object name

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I have manually mapped a pre-existing table to a model and dbcontext

[image]

```
namespace App.Monitoring.DbContext
{
    using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
    using App.Monitoring.DbContext.Models;

    public partial class Context: DbContext
    {
        public virtual DbSet<tDataLoad> tDataLoad { get; set; }

        public Context(DbContextOptions<Context> options) : 
        base(options)
        {

        }

        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {

        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<tDataLoad>(entity =>
            {
                entity.HasIndex(e => new { e.DataLoad_Id})
                    .IsUnique();

                entity.Property(e => e.DataLoad_Id)
                    .IsRequired()
                    .HasMaxLength(255);  

            });
       }
    }
}
```

But when I'm trying to access table

```
    _dataContext.tDataLoad.ToList();
```

I keep getting

[image]

Comment: That usually works. Is your table name exactly tDataLoad or something else? Does it exist in the dbo schema or elsewhere?

Comment: @TanveerBadar the table name is `CREATE TABLE [log].[tDataLoad]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are likely missing the schema specification in your mapping. Please use the following for proper configuration.

```
entity.ToTable("tDataLoad", "log");
```

Comment: Thanks.This has fixed the original issue. But now another one has popped up - `System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlNullValueException: Data is Null. This method or property cannot be called on Null values.`
 `

Comment: That's a separate problem. Please post a new question. But this is basically caused by things like having an int field while your table has null values in the corresponding column, or such.